# visual studio 2010 architect

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed the trial version of VSTS 2010 Beta 1, and I want to try out the Modeling projects, but when I try to create a new project, the modeling project is not on the list.
do I need to install anything else?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, It appear I downloaded the professional edition, though I was sure it was the team suite...downloaded again, installed, and life is good.